# Salesforce -- Anyone experiencing weird behavior of "wire"?

Tags: salesforce, lwc

Been learning Salesforce for a month now and this is the first weird stuff I have encountered and not a single documentation was able to help me

I have imported the wire from lwc properly

But whenever I'm deploying it, it says that a wire variable is NOT a known adapter, can anyone kindly help me out to resolve this please?

[image: Weird behavior]

Answer (score 0):

So dumb of me, the official documentation wasn't able to tell that I need to import some important tools

Aside from importing **wire**, we'll need the following:

```
import { publish, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
```

take note of this, especially those who want to use the LMS, or to communicate their component to another component that's not related at all